# flipping strings upside down racket

Tags: scheme, racket

I got the letters to turn upside down. `p` to `d` What I can't seem to do is get a string of words to turn upside down. Like `house` upside down to `ǝsnoɥ`.  any help would be appreciated. I am just about done. I am using beginning student with list abbreviations.

```
#;(first (first l2))
#;(first (rest l2))
#;(first (rest (first l2)))

(define (helper character list)
  (cond [(string=? character (first (first list))) (first (rest (first list)))]
        [else (helper character (rest list))]))

(check-expect (helper "p" table-1) "d")
(check-expect (helper "t" table-1) "ʇ")

;;_______________________________________________________________________________

(define (upside-down string)


(upside-down "cat")
```

Comment: I figured out another (Easier) way to do this though, using beginng student language. dont think ive ever gone over lambda

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of comments on your `helper` procedure:

- You should add an extra condition for the case when `character` is not in the list - if that happens, simply return the same `character`. Otherwise, an error will occur
- The parameter should not be named `list`, that's a built-in procedure and it's a bad practice to overwrite it
- Test it throughly before proceeding.

Once that's sorted out, here's how you could implement `upside-down`, fill-in the blanks:

```
(define (upside-down str)
  (<???>                       ; finally, do the opposite of explode on the list
   (map (lambda (c)            ; map over each of the characters
          (<???> <???> <???>)) ; call helper on the character
        (<???> (<???> str))))) ; reverse the exploded string
```

If you're not allowed to use `map` or `lambda`, then implement a `convert` procedure that iterates over each of the characters in the string and applies `helper` on each one, returning a list with the result of applying it - basically, implement you own [`map`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fmap..rkt%29._map%29%29) that always applies `helper` to each element in the input list:

```
(define (convert lst)
  <???>)

(convert '("c" "a" "t"))
=> '("ɔ" "ɐ" "ʇ")
```

Now we can write `upside-down` using `convert`:

```
(define (upside-down str)
  (<???>                   ; finally, do the opposite of explode on the list
   (convert                ; use our shiny new procedure
    (<???> (<???> str))))) ; reverse the exploded string
```

Comment: Thanks. But lambda? What language are you using? I am using beginning student with abreviations.

Comment: @JerryLynch see my updated answer, for a solution without `map` or `lambda`

Comment: I am not really sure. Shouldnt it be something similar to my helper fnction?

Comment: WOOOOOO. I figured it out! Thanks.

Comment: @JerryLynch excellent! I'm really glad :)